# Catch COM events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, com

Trying to wire up a COM library that we use to talk to things in .NET. In VB6, the same thing could of been done by just doing

```
private withevents _monitor as new Application
```

and then I could just do

```
monitor_onPrintText(byval msg as string, byval draw as boolean)
```

and it would work, whenever something was printed on the monitor side, it would fire the event and send us stuff back. However, in C#, I'm able to execute the commands, but I don't get the normal things back like I do in VB6. I'm just curious as to what I'm doing wrong, as everything I've read says

```
_monitor.onPrintText += onPrintText;
```

should work, but I'm not able to get the event to fire.

I've tried [this codeproject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990/Understanding-Classic-COM-Interoperability-With-NE#DelegatesNET), [and MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66ahbe6y.aspx), and a bunch of other resources out there, but I can't get this damn thing to work! Here is the basics of the code, I've added all three "interfaces" created by importing the com object, and I've tried all kinds of different combinations. My "startup" script should return a true, and fire the onPrintText event a few times with some messages along the way (or at least thats what it's doing in VB6...)

```
using System;
using monitorLib;

public class MyClass 
{
    private Application _monitor;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _monitor = new Application;
        _monitor.onPrintText += onPrintText;

        // Doing this runs a "script" which causes the 
        // event to fire whenever print is called from it.
        _monitor.evaluate("run(\"startup\");"); 
    }


    public dynamic Evaluate(string pScript)
    {
        return _monitor.evaluate(pScript);
    }

    public void PrintText(string p_text, bool p_drawNow)
    {
        debug.print(p_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do.  Do you want to send text to the `COM` object? Or do you want to capture events fired by the `COM` object? or both?

Comment: Edited based on suggestions from Hans

Comment: Did you try the `var source = (IApplicationEvents_Events)_monitor;` as suggested by @Hans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public class MyClass : IApplication, IApplicationEvents, IApplicationEvents_Event
```

Something went very wrong here.  Maybe it is intentional but it is doubtful.  It is the *server* that implements the interfaces, the *client* just uses them.  You've written the kind of code that a server needs to write.  It must implement all of the interfaces that the server provides.  But MyClass certainly looks like client code that merely uses the server.

Not sure how you got into this pickle, maybe you've always written servers and never client code.  Another possible explanation is that COM allows a server to implement multiple interfaces that generates events.  Not something that you can do in C#.  To get ahead, you'll have to remove all of these inherited interfaces, and the code that you wrote to implement them.  Then either try:

```
public MyClass() {
    _monitor = new Application();
    _monitor.onPrintText += onPrintText;
}
```

As you'd normally write it.  If the event is not implemented by the default [source] interface then you may have to write:

```
public MyClass() {
    _monitor = new Application;
    var source = (IApplicationEvents_Events)_monitor;
    source.onPrintText += onPrintText;
}
```

But that's just a guess, I can't see what you can see in Object Browser.  That it doesn't work right now is expected, you ended up listening to your own events.

Comment: Anything specific you need from the Object browser? I edited my post with your suggestions, tried both methods and the event still isn't firing.

Comment: Well, all I've figured out from the edit is that you didn't actually mean to implement these interfaces.  So you really did mean to implement the client and not the server.  Progress.  I have no idea yet when the COM server is going to fire the event.

Comment: I actually just got it working, turns out I was using application and not ApplicationClass. I had tried applicationClass earlier, but because I was implementing all the interfaces, it was causing it to error out. (Circle reference, I think?)

Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Think of your `COM` component just like you would any other library or 3rd party software.

Interfaces from the `COM` would be used to *extend* the functionality of the component.  They would not be needed if you are just trying to send or get information to or from your component.

Your code looks ok if you are just trying to get or send info to the `COM` component.

You need to:

1. Remove all the interfaces from your class declaration.
2. Remove the `IApplicationEvents_onPrintTextEventHandler` method.
3. Add a reference of your `COM` control to your project then instantiate it as whatever type it is.

(Hint: `Application` is very probably not the type of your control)

As long as this control has an event called `onPrintText` and a method called `evaluate` then you are calling them just fine.

Comment: I've edited the post to be more clear. (this is what I actually had before I just started trying everything)

technically, application is monitorLib.Application.

Comment: I see, well i think your first try was closer.  Points for bringing you back into focus! :) Did you try the `var source = (IApplicationEvents_Events)_monitor;`?

Comment: Actually, you might be right... I noticed that Application was an interface. There is a class called ApplicationClass that seems to contain many of the same things? I think because earlier I was inheriting all those other classes, it wasn't letting me use it. (circular reference probably?)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a idiot, it is the ApplicationClass. Looks like I just got a little carried away experimenting and all the interfaces were messing with my mind. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Ahh... that sounds better!  trying to instantiate an interface would cause problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37291/discussion-between-calvin-and-paqogomez)